# Display Arabic text in Rich TextBox

Tags: vb6, richtextbox, arabic

Hi i am using VB6 and I have a field in my DB which stores Arabic text like "ÓÔÄÇåì". Now I want to display this in RichTextbox. I have set RichTextBox1.Font.CharSet property to 178 and RichTextBox1.Font.Name to Arial. But still it's not displaying in the correct format which is "سشؤاهى". Please help.

Comment: use the RichEdit from this Unicode suite: [Replacement of the MS common controls](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?841929-VB6-ActiveX-CommonControls-%28Replacement-of-the-MS-common-controls%29)

Answer (score 1):

- You can use the Text Object Model (tom) type library to get Unicode access to the RichEdit control wrapped within a RichTextBox.
- You can use API calls to get Unicode access to the same thing.
- You can replace usage of the RichTextBox with another control, for example the InkEdit control that ships as part of Windows beginning in Vista.  Turn off the ink capture capability and you have a Unicode RTF box via the normal properties (.Text, .TextRTF, etc.).

All of this presumes that your database actually contains Unicode text.